# MVC Form Action Automatically Changed by Areas

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In my main layout (root), I added search tools (a textbox and a button) to find the products.

_Layout.cs

```
<form action="@Url.Action("SearchProduct", "Product")" id="frmSearchProduct" method="get" class="form-inline text-right">
    <input type="text" name="ProductName" placeholder="Enter Product Name" class="form-control" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i></button>
</form>
```

The search function works properly, but if I opened page in Areas and clicked the button, it doesn't work. The form action (url) is changed depend on the Areas.

> http://localhost:49458/Error/NotFound?aspxerrorpath=/Workflow/Product/SearchProduct

There is no ProductController in Workflow Areas, so that it generates the error. How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try with

```
@Url.Action("SearchProduct", "Product", new { area = string.Empty })
```